# how to pass multiple parameters between view and controller in .net core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

in the conversion between traditional MVC and .net core, i am coming across something quirky when I use almost the same code in  both technologies.

I am passing parameters of both an id field and the name of the sending controller from the  view to the receiving controller. The  code below works in traditional MVC:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    @Html.ActionLink("New Comment", "Create", "ServiceRequestNotes", new { ServiceRequest = item.Id, returncontroller = "ServiceRequests" }, null)<br />
</td>
```

And

```
// POST: ServiceRequestNotes/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,NoteDescription,LastUpdated,WrittenBy,ServiceRequest")] ServiceRequestNote serviceRequestNote, string returncontroller)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ServiceRequestNotes.Add(serviceRequestNote);
        serviceRequestNote.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        serviceRequestNote.WrittenBy = User.Identity.Name;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("Index", returncontroller);
    }
    ViewBag.ServiceRequest = new SelectList(db.ServiceRequests, "Id", "RequestHeading", serviceRequestNote.ServiceRequest);
    return View(serviceRequestNote);
}
```

The returncontroller value is populated immediately when i debug and it saves successfully

I have almost the same code in .net Core

```
<td>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a> |
    @Html.ActionLink("New Comment", "Create", "ServiceRequestNotes", new { ServiceRequest = item.Id, returncontroller = "TeamServiceRequests" }, null)<br />
</td>
```

and

```
// POST: ServiceRequestNotes/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,NoteDescription,LastUpdated,WrittenBy,ServiceRequest")] ServiceRequestNotes serviceRequestNotes, string returncontroller)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(serviceRequestNotes);
        serviceRequestNotes.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        serviceRequestNotes.WrittenBy = User.Identity.Name;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        return RedirectToAction("Index", returncontroller);
    }
    ViewData["ServiceRequest"] = new SelectList(_context.ServiceRequests, "Id", "RequestDescription", serviceRequestNotes.ServiceRequest);
    return View(serviceRequestNotes);
}
```

However in debugging- when it reaches the public async create line, the value of returncontroller is null.

It still saves the comment, but because the above is null it return to the index view of notescontroller rather than the originating one.

Anybody have any idea why in .net core, the returncontroller value is coming up as null when the code is almost identical? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how you can claim in works in mvc (prior core versions) - a link makes a GET, not a POST and you `[HttpPost]` methods cannot be hit.

Comment: im not sure i understand :(

Comment: You cannot execute a `[HttpPost]` method using a link (and have never been able to). You need a `<form>` that makes a POST (or an ajax call)

Comment: The code above pre-core does work. Maybe another way to ask the question - is if you have 3 different actionlinks from 3 different  views  calling another view in  another controller, how do you store where you came from so that you can returntoaction to the original calling view, action, and controller? Its the edit view and action in the calling/originating controller i want to go back too? Thanks - sorry if i sounds dense. Looked up many passing paramater examples - nothing so far doing it. i must be missing something.

Comment: trying to store orginiating controller name in a string and  pass that as parameter to the httppost action which is in this case is uploading a file. uploading etc works- just cant navigate back when finished

Comment: Again, an  `<a>` tag makes a GET, not a POST (and it has always been that way). I can only assume that the methods you are claiming worked previously did not have the `[HttpPost]` attribute (or the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute)

Comment: i finally solved it used TempData in both the get and post. The httpget transferred the value of the parameter, so i used to TempData to make sure httppost action result recieved it